# using dynamic index after nth repetition pattern regex get timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regex-lookarounds

i'm using a regex pattern that based on a dynamic index the current occurence gets matched line per line. However, when the text start to be too long the pattern gets a time out (instead in javascript after a bit the regex engine crush it). I've
tried to improve this solution in this way:
`(?<=(?:\btest\b(.|\n)*){index})(?<!(?:\btest\b(.|\n)*){index+1})\btest\b` (here the original pattern solution [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GALozt/1))

might be possible to be related with the backtracking problem?

ps. index in regex pattern is dynamic because is applied in js context.

Comment: NEVER use `(.|\n)*`, it is the worst regex construct ever.

Comment: @Markus, Can you give a bit of context on how this is used in JavaScript, so we can maybe suggest alternatives?

Comment: nono is `{0}{1} then {1}{2}`..ect ect

Comment: yes. There is a syntax highlither (is a react component) that based on regex pattern underline the specific word, so basically this pattern gets two index (`the current and the current+1`), thus in this way the selection come on a single word repeated for the number of occurence founded. the movement of selection is triggerend by next or previous button.

Comment: If you would have a function that would return you the start (and end) position of the word in the string, given `current`, would that work out for you? It would still be good to see the actual (relevant) JavaScript code to see what the steps are to pass the necessary information for the highlighting position.

Comment: actually, i'm using this component but i think that is not possible to pass it the word of the string's position because it accepts only a pattern regex, [demo Highlight](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highlight-regex-demo-forked-019uh7?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the react-highlight-regex package does not have any way to indicate the part to highlight in any other way.

To avoid the enormous possibilities of backtracking that your regex has, you should avoid that this `(.|\n)` would capture the keyword ("test" in your example).

You could try with this to match the third word "Hello":

```
(?<=^(?:(?:(?!\bHello\b)[^])*\bHello\b){2}(?:(?!\bHello\b)[^])*)\bHello\b
```

Remove the `\b` if you want to count also "Hello" in "Hellos", ...etc.